# settxfee: formula for fixed fee

Tags: bitcoind

I want to set fixed fee rate for transaction. I calculated tx size which is 222( [here is this tx](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/testnet/transaction/d8c00cc75dde9b1f29e0f06e9da766a8b24cd30e515ac50cd1533cc27a67ae87)), called rpc `settxfee`

```
$o->settxfee(sprintf('%f', (0.00001/222)*1000));
```

and sent to the network. I supposed fee would set for tx to 0.00001 but set to 0.00000662 TBTC instead. Here is wallet info  `"paytxfee": 0.00004500,`, seems  `settxfee` worked as expected. What do I do wrong?

Comment: for some reason blockchair doesn't show vbytes for testnet as it does for mainnet, blockstream block explorer instead shows it: https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/d8c00cc75dde9b1f29e0f06e9da766a8b24cd30e515ac50cd1533cc27a67ae87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big disclaimer: you really shouldn't do this. Transaction prioritization works based on fee per size, so that's what you should be configuring.

As for an explanation of what you're seeing: the block explorer you're using is showing the wrong size. For fee computations what you need is the *vsize*, not the serialized size. This is the size that takes the discount for witness data introduced by BIP141 (segwit) into account.

The vsize of your transaction is 141, not 222.